# JMeter - Web report - Response time over time show only average

Tags: jmeter

I configured some (really simple) load test.
In this case it will just target a single URL with 1 thread for 10 seconds (with a throughput of 100 requests max). It's just a preparation for the real load test so it's normal numbers are limited.

When I run it into the GUI I'm able to see this graph "response times over time" :
[image]

Since I'm not supposed to run heavy load test with the GUI I tested the command line provided when you launch the GUI. (When you launch the GUI you have a warning to not use the GUI to do some heavy tests and they provide you a command line to run the tests and generate the report).
The command line is : jmeter -n -t "MyFile.jmx" -l "e:/temp/result6/result.csv" -e -o "e:/temp/result6"

Everything is going OK and the report is generated.
The "csv" file show me there is 16 samples and the web dashboard show me the same thing :

[image]

But when I try to see the "response times over time" I only get a single dot:
[image]

When I put my cursor over the dot I get this:
[image]

It seems the report is only generated with the average result (which is of course a single dot...).

In the top right of the schema there is a "display all samples" button but no effect (I suppose it's just to come back when you zoom on the schema and you don't see all the samples anymore).

I guess this is not the "normal" behavior but I checked the CLI documentation and I don't see anything wrong with my command that could cause this...

Hope you'll get an idea!

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test runs 9 seconds only and by default HTML Reporting Dashboard has [overall granularity](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general) set to 1 minute

If you want to see the chart you need to decrease the granularity to i.e. 1 second or even less, add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000
```

and next time you run your test you should see the chart instead of dot in the reporting dashboard.

Alternatively you can pass the property via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
 jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000 -n -t -f "MyFile.jmx" -l "e:/temp/result6/result.csv" -e -o "e:/temp/result6"
```

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)

Comment: Exactly the response I needed. Thanks sir :-)